# Counting number of RadioGroups and RadioButtons

Tags: android, radio-button, radio-group

How to get the number of RadioGroups added dynamically in Layout and number of RadioButtons added in respective RadioGroup??

Comment: use `anyView.getChildCount();`

Answer (score 1):

What you can do here is obtain a reference to the container of the layout. For Ex -

```
RelativeLayout rl=(RelativeLayout)findViewbyId(R.id.relative);
System.out.println(rl.getChildCount());
```

This will print the childs of the container view. If your layout contains only radiobuttons, your job is done.

Hope this helps! :)